# Enforcing 1 unique websocket connection per client?

Tags: web, go, websocket

I have a webpage that establishes a websocket connection with the server. I have to make sure that a user of the site can only establish a single connection, so opening a new tab and navigating to the same page will close the previous connection.

I was thinking of maintaining a map with the session id as the key; however, as the map would have to be constantly adjusted in size as more and more clients connect I am afraid of it having performance problems, and since it's accessed concurrently you would probably have to do some kind of locking.

Any ideas for performance efficient ways of ensuring a unique connection per client? Would love to hear suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Have you considered storing the connections unique identifier in a secure HTTPOnly cookie? If that doesn't exist, issue a new one, if it does you know what their connection is. You can avoid maintaining his stuff server side by depending on the browser to maintain that state in a secure fashion.

Comment: I see what you mean, you would check for whether that cookie exists. However, I would prefer to perform server side checking, it would be easy to remove that particular cookie and establish a new connection.

Comment: You do the check on the server. The cookie is HTTPOnly so the only way it's gonna get removed is if the user clears their cookies in which case their session will probably be hosed anyway so you'll have to give them a new connection. Think of an HTTPOnly cookie as a server side resource because that's really what it is. You control it, the browser carries it along for you, nothing can touch it, it's your storage.

Comment: I think I can make that work. Thanks for the advice, appreciate it!

Comment: This doesnt stop someone from using Chrome in incognito mode, or firefox + chrome.  Also, an in-memory map doesn't allow you to scale past 1 server... unless you have a means of doing src address based sticky balancing or something like that

Comment: Think that such behavior may not be what your users expect. People expect to open a new browser and have a fully functional page. You may be shooting yourself in the feet.

Comment: David Budworth makes some good points. I hadn't considered multiple browsers and the scaling issue. I ended doing it through a flag in the database, since it had to be accessed and written to anyway, it could freeload off of that, and the fact that its meant to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be concerned about the performance of the solution outlined in the question. If you want to close the previous connection, there's no way around maintaining server side maps. Assuming a single server and that you are using the Gorilla websocket package, the following code should do the trick:

```
var (
   mu sync.Mutex
   conns map[string]*websocket.Conn
)

func addConn(sessionID string, conn *websocket.Conn) {
   mu.Lock()
   prev := conns[sessionID]
   conns[sessionID] = conn
   mu.Unlock()
   if prev != nil {
      // Close will stop concurrent reads and writes.
      prev.Close()
   }
}

func removeConn(sessionID string, conn *websocket.Conn) {
   mu.Lock()
   // We don't simply delete(conns, session) to avoid race on cleanup.
   if conns[sessionID] == conn {
      delete(conns, sessionID)
   }
   mu.Unlock()
}
```

The cost of updating this map is small compared to the cost of accepting an incoming network connection, completing websocket handshake and everything else that's happening in scenario.